# Running previous run command that was run in normal mode using colon

Tags: command-line, normal-mode, repeated-commands

Recently I had to compile a latex file a few times, `:!pdflatex filename.tex` did the trick. But is there a way in normal mode to repeat commands like these which are in the recent history,but used repeatedly for a short time.

Setting keybinding to for `:command` is not what I am looking for, since the command is used only for a short time.

Comment: See `:help @:`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thats what I was looking for. I did'nt know that these special registers existed for recording also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ralf mentions in the comments, the `:` register always contains the last colon command.

So, `@:` will replay the last command, and `@@` should work after that.

In addition, you can `:<Up>` for command line history, or use `q:` for the command line window.

Comment: Also: If you enter `:!p<Up>` it will only fetch commands from the history, that begin with `!p`.